# Normalizing lighting conditions for image recognition

Tags: opencv, image-processing, object-detection

I am using OpenCV to process a video to identify frames containing objects using a rudimentary algorithm (background subtraction → brightness threshold → dilation → contour detection).

The video is shot over the course of a day, so lighting conditions are gradually changing, so I expect it would improve my results if I did some sort of brightness and/or contrast normalization step first.

Answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57030125/automatically-adjusting-brightness-of-image-with-opencv) suggest using `convertScaleAbs`, or contrast optimization with histogram clipping, or [histogram equalization](https://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d5/daf/tutorial_py_histogram_equalization.html).

Of these techniques or others, what would be the best preprocessing step to normalize the frames?

Comment: If you capture video in you application, you can improve image quality through  exposure time. `VideoCapture` has a method for it, though not all cameras are supported.

Comment: Unfortunately these videos were collected years ago and I cannot change how the frames were captured. And I think increasing exposure time would greatly increase motion blur, right?

Comment: whats the background subtraction technique?

Comment: @Masoud It is just `cv2.accumulateWeighted` to average the current frame with the accumulated background, and `cv2.absdiff` to subtract the background from the frame.

Comment: Well, estimating the background over a limited period of time may help you overcome high brightness changes. Also, to compensate the brightness change, you can use [mixture models](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixture_model#Gaussian_mixture_model) so a model for the brighness change and another model for the foreground.